# MSBuild different build configurations for different solutions?

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I'm using TFS Build Server to build about 10 solutions. Most of these solutions are configured to build as "Any CPU", however one has a hard dependency on a 64 bit dll and must be built as x64. I tried to add x64 to the configuration under Process > Build > Configurations, but it tries to build all solutions as Any CPU and x64.

Is there a way to pick a different configuration for each solution?

Answer (score 0):

Each solution should have it's own build that can be configured independently.

If you have dependencies between solutions you should publish nugget packages and depend on them.